# hide session and cookie data in error page in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Whenever i got an error in yii2 application it shows session and cookie information.

```
$_COOKIE = [
'advanced-backend' => 'd9ao5cmemmnte4epb69mkuore1',
'_identity-backend' => '9f1de7abef3bcb3b520d1a6caa06defc181307c5f227cb3bf06477428d021366a:2:{i:0;s:17:"_identity-backend";i:1;s:16:"[51,144,2592000]";}',
];

$_SESSION = [
'__flash' => [],
'__returnUrl' => '/oms/',
'UserID' => '51',
'UserName' => 'alesh@example.com.np',
'FullName' => 'Alesh',
'EmployeeID' => '53',
'RoleID' => '423',
'SupervisorID' => '342',
'SupervisorName' => 'USER',
'Menus' => 'leave,attendance,dailyreport,myinfo',
'Role' => 'employee',
'__id' => 51,
'__expire' => 1520506157,
];
```

as this cant be secure to show these things to user how to hide or remove these things when user get an error??

Comment: technically you don't use ENV_DEV for production, hence no trace would be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In home directory of your project, you have a index.php file, just need to change first and second line of this file to :

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');
```

this change, can change your project to production mode and hide any error of your site, but error stored in project_root\runtime\logs